# ORA-01000: nombre maximum de curseurs ouverts dépassé

Tags: hibernate, oracle10g

I upgrade from **hibernate 3** to **4.3.0** with **spring 3.2.2**.
After running my project, I got this exception:

> WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error:
>   1000, SQLState: 72000 ERROR:
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-01000: nombre
>   maximum de curseurs ouverts dépassé

I tried `ALTER SYSTEM SET open_cursors = 10000 SCOPE=BOTH;` however the number of current open cursors is 47.
That didn't resolve my problem.

I tried adding finally `entityManager.close()`
and the exception persists

I tried with `ojdbc6.jar, ojdbc5.jar,` and no changes

Have you please any idea about solving that issue ?.
Big thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using refresh your lib folder.

Prove the exitance of the jar `hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar`.

HTH